# getting line-based text data application/json instead of json object in wireshark trace

Tags: android, json

I am trying to send data as json object to a server, but failing to do so.
Took wireshark trace and found out that it is sending as line based text data.
Unable to find the issue , attaching part of the code.

```
public void post(View view) {

    if (contents2 != null) {
        new JSONtask().execute(contents2);
    }
}


public class JSONtask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    public String result;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {

            // 1. URL
            URL url = new URL("URL");
            final String contents2 = params[0];

            // 2. Open connection
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // 3. Specify POST method
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // 4. Set the headers
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // 5. Add JSON data into POST request body


            //`5.1 Use Jackson object mapper to convert Contnet object into JSON
            //ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            // 5.2 Get connection output stream
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            // 5.3 Copy Content "JSON" into
            wr.writeBytes(contents2);

            // 5.4 Send the request
            wr.flush();

            // 5.5 close
            wr.close();

            // 6. Get the response
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // 7. Print result
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            result = response.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            result =e.getMessage();

        }
        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String page)
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Any suggestion on what can be done or what i am missing will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mohit ,have added the logcat i hope it is of some help.

Comment: still stuck with the issue...:(

Comment: your error show some wifi issue...can you post in which line error occur

Answer (score 0):

@Mohit thanx for your time, i found the issue.
Problem was object mismatch, data sent was not matching to what was expected at the server end, once it was made correct issue got resolved.